# dojo FileUploader with express.js

Tags: dojo, express

I am trying to upload image using dojo FileUploader on client side and express.js on server side. After image upload is complete I want to preview the uploaded image.
here is my code :-

Ajax request for Image Upload :-

```
require(['dojo/dom','dojo/_base/array','dojo/dom-construct','dojo/query',"dojo/request",'dojo/on',"dojox/form/FileUploader","dojo/domReady!"],function(dom,array,domConstruct,query,xhr,on,FileUploader)
    {
       var upld = new FileUploader(
       {
        degradable:true,
        uploadUrl:'http://localhost:8005/testy',
        uploadOnChange:false,
        title:'uploader,
        isDebug:true,
        devMode:true
       },'test');

       on(upld,'change',function(data)
       {
        array.forEach(data,function(d)
        {
           dom.byId('filename').innerHTML = d.name;
            });
       });
       on(upld,'complete',function(data)
       {
        array.forEach(data, function(d)
        {
           dom.byId("rgtCol").innerHTML += '<img src="'+d.file+'" />';
        });
       });
       on(dom.byId('btn'),'click',function(evt)
       {
        upld.upload();
       });
    });
```

html code:-

```
<div id='test'>Uploader</div>
<div id='filename'></div>
<div id='rgtCol'></div>
<input type='button'  id='btn' label='submit' />
```

server side code:-
 here is my server side code :-

```
    var express = require('express'),
    fs = require('fs');
    app = express.createServer();

    app.use(express.bodyParser())
    app.post('/testy', function(req, res)
    {
      var filename = req.body.Filename;
      var body = req.files.flashUploadFiles.path;  
      fs.createReadStream(body).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('tmp/' + filename));

      res.send('tmp/' + filename);
    });  

app.listen(8005);
```

My problem is that image is uploaded but I not able to give preview of uploaded image on client side. I am able to do these using php file on server side but not in express.js

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to pushing back binary data (like images) to the user, I happen to use [binaryJS](http://binaryjs.com/). Its built upon socketIO and you can trigger the preview after the upload is finished by giving

```
server.on('connection', function(client){
  // Stream a flower as a hello!
  var file = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/flower.png');
  client.send(file); 
});
```

This way you can send the image to the user as a preview. You might want to create a thumbnail via ImageMagick if you want, but thats an extra. The example I showed you is the [hello world example of binaryJS](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/tree/master/examples/helloworld).